# UPDATE: Trying to pull a value from multiple rows by multiple criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

OK - I had my logic wrong on this the first time around. I was trying to use SUMIFS but further research makes it look like I need to use SUMPRODUCT.

I am trying to run a calculation in Google Sheets that will sum the value of a single column based on matching two row values: matching the MONTH in the first cell of my ‘target’ table, and specific values in the ‘data’ table.

SAMPLE TABLE HERE

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EpRDGHqrXWpjGxeDlofy5LitI1BdZpSG6V0fbBwrIoE/edit?usp=sharing

FOR INSTANCE….

MY TARGET TABLE: COL A, COL B

| DATE | SPEND |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | CALC HERE |
| 02/01/2022 | CALC HERE |

MY DATA TABLE: COL A,COL B,COL C

| DATE | NAME | DOLLARS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/28/2022 | Bill | $.50 |
| 01/29/2022 | Ted | $1.00 |
| 01/29/2022 | Ted | $1.50 |
| 01/30/2022 | Bill | $2.00 |
| 02/01/2022 | Ted | $3.00 |
| 02/01/2022 | Bill | $4.00 |
| 02/01/2022 | Ted | $5.00 |
| 02/02/2022 | Bill | $6.00 |
| 02/02/2022 | Ted | $7.00 |
| 02/02/2022 | Bill | $8.00 |

I want to pull the total sum of DOLLARS from DATA TABLE Col C into TARGET TABLE Col B if the dates in COL A are in the same month AND the NAME VALUE in COL B Match. For instance, Ted's Total in January, Ted's Total in February.

So in my TARGET TABLE if I were matching for TED, I would get

| DATE | SPEND |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | $2.50 |
| 02/01/2022 | $15.00 |

For now I've had to resort to hard-coding a date range into a SUMPRODUCT equation...it works if I don't try to match the NAME in COL B (see CELL B5 in TARGET TABLE worksheet), but when I add that criteria, the equation breaks (see CELL B4 in TARGET TABLE worksheet)

Here is the equation that works:

=SUMPRODUCT(('DATA TABLE'!$C$2:$C),--(DATE(YEAR('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),MONTH('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),1)>=DATE(2022,2,1)),--(DATE(YEAR('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),MONTH('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),1)<=DATE(2022,2,28)))

Here is the equation that gives me a FORMULA PARSE ERROR.

=SUMPRODUCT(('DATA TABLE'!$C$2:$C),--(DATE(YEAR('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),MONTH('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),1)>=DATE(2022,2,1)),--(DATE(YEAR('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),MONTH('DATA TABLE'!$A$2:$A),1)<=DATE(2022,2,28)),--('DATA TABLE'!$B$2:$B,="Ted"))

Thanks for any assistance with this!

Comment: Shouldn't `$B$2:$B2,"Ted")` in your formula, be just `$B$2:$B,"Ted")`? So that all the ranges have the same size

Comment: The most efficient route to getting help is usually to share a link to your sample spreadsheet so that the volunteer contributors have that starting data and layout to work with. As it stands, volunteer contributors here would have to start a new spreadsheet of their own, guess at where your target table is located (same sheet, new sheet), end all the data... and only *then* be able to start thinking about a solution.

Comment: Thanks AJPerez and Erik.

I will link to a sample sheet!

Comment: OK - SO changing the formula to  $B$2:$B,"Ted") as per @AJPerez's recommendations helped fix this but only to match the exact date and not any date in a given month. I am looking at a different approach and will post with a Google Sheets link since I think this is going to require using SUMPRODUCT. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to "lead the witness" with titles, post details, tags or comments that tell people how to solve the issue (e.g., `SUMIFS` or `SUMPRODUCT`, etc.). Instead, just describe the issue you are trying to solve and provide easily accessible data with desired outcome.

That said, I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"SPEND";IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({'DATA TABLE'!A2:C},"Select Col1, SUM(Col3) WHERE Col2 ='Ted' GROUP BY Col1"),2,FALSE),0))})`

This single formula will produce the header (which can be changed within the formula itself if needed) and all results for all rows. As things were when I left the formula, all row results were the same only because you had the same date entered in all rows of Col A. Change what is in Col A and the formula will retrieve results for that date and "Ted" in Col B.

Here, you see that neither `SUMIF` nor `SUMPRODUCT` was used. Instead, I created a reference table with `QUERY` that is written to only contain data for "Ted", and then I used `VLOOKUP` to search that table by date per row (hence `ArrayFormula`).